# importing to a table with lookup fields

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I have a database with multiple fields that are repeated many many times. My first instinct has been to create a new table for these repeating fields and relate them to a table via look up fields. Is that a correct way of thinking? If not, what's the best way to do this?

If so, is it still going to be possible to import into a table with all of these lookup fields?

Comment: You are right. you can use lookup field. But i have use typecode(Int) field and list the typecode in the tblType table. Please read on [Database_normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Can you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16363703/edit) your question to give us an example of the types of entries that are being repeated and the separate table you would put them in?